# creating scheduled api using civix

Tags: scheduled-job, civix

I am using civix to create a scheduled task with

```
civix generate:api --schedule Daily chiroContact assignAnimatorCourseResponsibleLabel
```

The files get created correctly, and the new api possibility is shown in the api explorer, however when I try and test it the result is

```
    {


"error_code": "not-found",
"entity": "ChiroContact",
"action": "assignanimatorcourseresponsiblelabel",
"is_error": 1,
"error_message": "API (ChiroContact, assignanimatorcourseresponsiblelabel) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)"
```

}

The sheduled task also doesn appear in the list of sheduled tasks in the system settings. Am I doing something wrong in creating this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your action is way too long and possibly separated into a few words in your function name? Can you check?

Comment: the full function name is civicrm_api3_chiro_contact_AssignAnimatorCourseResponsibleLabel.

Is there a limit on how long these names can be?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any physical limit but I tend to stick to a max of 2 camel cases :-) For example createocrr. And I would not use the camel cases in the civix command, so I would have done: civix generate:api --schedule Daily chiroContact assignanimatorcourseresponsiblelabel

Comment: Apparently that did it. Thank you very much